# Merge sort but it doesn't sort it

Tags: python, mergesort

I was trying to create an online store type of code, the code runs but it doesn't sort it well.

code:

```
class Product:

    def __init__(self, hproduct, htype, hprice, havail):
        self.name = hproduct
        self.type = htype
        self.price = hprice
        self.avail = havail
    def view(self):
        print(self.name.ljust(35), self.type.ljust(28), str(self.price).ljust(8), self.avail)
    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self.name > other.name
            
        
    

item_001 = Product('Tyma TD-10E Dreadnought', 'Acoustic Guitar', 23450, 'In Stock')
item_002 = Product('Baton Rouge AR21C/ME Traveler', 'Acoustic Guitar', 14900, 'In Stock')
item_003 = Product('Phoebus Baby 30 GS Mini', 'Acoustic Guitar', 6900, 'In Stock')
item_004 = Product('Maestro Project X X1-V1 OM', 'Acoustic Guitar', 32500, 'In Stock')
item_005 = Product('Sire A4 Grand Auditorium', 'Acoustic Guitar', 27490, 'In Stock')

item_006 = Product('Tagima TW55', 'Electric Guitar', 9500, 'In Stock')
item_007 = Product('Epiphone G400 ', 'Electric Guitar', 19500, 'In Stock')
item_008 = Product('D’Angelico Premiere DC', 'Electric Guitar', 49000, 'In Stock')
item_009 = Product('PRS Silver Sky', 'Electric Guitar', 138950, 'In Stock')
item_010 = Product('Vintage V100 Reissued', 'Electric Guitar', 27950, 'In Stock')

item_011 = Product('Phoebus Buddie 30 GS-E', 'Bass Guitar', 8720, 'In Stock')
item_012 = Product('Sire U5', 'Bass Guitar', 27490, 'In Stock')
item_013 = Product('Lakland Skyline Vintage J', 'Bass Guitar', 82950, 'In Stock')
item_014 = Product('Schecter Model T Session 5', 'Bass Guitar', 45900, 'In Stock')
item_015 = Product('Tagima Millenium Coda 4', 'Bass Guitar', 14900, 'In Stock')

item_016 = Product('Boss Katana 50 Mk II ', 'Accessory', 15950, 'In Stock')
item_017 = Product('TC Electronic BH250 Micro Bass', 'Accessory', 18990, 'In Stock')
item_018 = Product('Kemper Profiler Powerhead', 'Accessory', 130000, 'In Stock')
item_019 = Product('Headrush Pedal Board', 'Accessory', 27490, 'In Stock')
item_020 = Product('NUX MG30', 'Accessory', 12900, 'In Stock')

inventory = [item_001, item_002, item_003, item_004, item_005, item_006, item_007, item_008, item_009, item_010, item_011, item_012, item_013, item_014, item_015, item_016, item_017, item_018, item_019, item_020]

#Overall View Function
def view_inv(alist):

    hproduct = "Item Name"
    htype = "Type"
    hprice = "Price"
    havail = "Availability"

    print("\n", hproduct.ljust(35), htype.ljust(28), hprice.ljust(8), havail, "\n")
    for i in range(len(alist)):
        alist[i].view()
        if i%5 == 4:
            print("")
            
#Main function
import sys
def main():
    print("Welcome to the offline guitar store!")
    print("What would you like to do?")
    print("1: View all items")
    print("2: Sort items")
    print("3: Search items")
    print("4: Exit Program")
    
    choice = input("Your Choice: ")              
        
    if choice == '1':
        view_inv(inventory)
    elif choice =='2':
        sorting(inventory)
    elif choice =='3':
        searching(inventory)
    elif choice == '4':
        print("Thank you for using the program!")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid input. Try Again\n")

    main()

def sorting(alist):
    print("\nPlease choose sorting criteria")
    print("1: Sort by Name")
    print("2: Sort by Price")
    print("3: Reset Sort")
    choice = input("Your Choice: ")
    param = ''

    if choice == '1':
        param = 'name'
        sorrtt(alist)
        #sort(alist, 0, len(alist)-1, param): Modify this to call your main sort algorithm
        view_inv(alist)
    elif choice =='2':
        param = 'price'
        #sort(alist, 0, len(alist)-1, param): Modify this to call your main sort algorithm
        view_inv(alist)
    elif choice =='3':
        alist[:] = [item_001, item_002, item_003, item_004, item_005, item_006, item_007, item_008, item_009, item_010, item_011, item_012, item_013, item_014, item_015, item_016, item_017, item_018, item_019, item_020]
        view_inv(alist)
    else:
        print("Invalid input. Try Again")
        sorting(alist)

def sorrtt(alist):
    if len(alist)>1: 
        mid = len(alist)//2 
        lefthalf = alist[:mid]
        righthalf = alist[mid:] 
    
        sorrtt(lefthalf) 
        sorrtt(righthalf) 
    
        i=0 
        j=0
        k=0
    
        while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i].__lt__(righthalf[j]): 
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i] 
                i=i+1
            elif righthalf[j].__lt__(lefthalf[i]):
                alist[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
        k=k+1
        while i < len(lefthalf):
            alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1
    
        while j < len(righthalf):
            alist[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
```

Expected Output is that it's sorted according to the first letter of the product's name, intead it prints out this:

```
    NUX MG30                            Accessory                    12900    In Stock
Baton Rouge AR21C/ME Traveler       Acoustic Guitar              14900    In Stock
Phoebus Baby 30 GS Mini             Acoustic Guitar              6900     In Stock
Maestro Project X X1-V1 OM          Acoustic Guitar              32500    In Stock
Sire A4 Grand Auditorium            Acoustic Guitar              27490    In Stock

Tagima TW55                         Electric Guitar              9500     In Stock
Epiphone G400                       Electric Guitar              19500    In Stock
D’Angelico Premiere DC              Electric Guitar              49000    In Stock
PRS Silver Sky                      Electric Guitar              138950   In Stock
Vintage V100 Reissued               Electric Guitar              27950    In Stock

Phoebus Buddie 30 GS-E              Bass Guitar                  8720     In Stock
Sire U5                             Bass Guitar                  27490    In Stock
Lakland Skyline Vintage J           Bass Guitar                  82950    In Stock
Schecter Model T Session 5          Bass Guitar                  45900    In Stock
Tagima Millenium Coda 4             Bass Guitar                  14900    In Stock

Boss Katana 50 Mk II                Accessory                    15950    In Stock
TC Electronic BH250 Micro Bass      Accessory                    18990    In Stock
Kemper Profiler Powerhead           Accessory                    130000   In Stock
Headrush Pedal Board                Accessory                    27490    In Stock
NUX MG30                            Accessory                    12900    In Stock
```

I don't understand what's causing the problem, so any tips will very much help me, thanks!

Comment: Why aren't you using the built-in `list.sort()` method?

Comment: Please post a [mre]. If you're just having a problem with the sorting code, we don't need to see all the other code.

Comment: Why are you calling `.__lt__()` instead of just using `<`?

Comment: Shouldn't your `__lt__()` method use `<` rather than `>`?

Comment: I tried using < and >, but it's the same error, i also used .__lt__() because I needed to compare the names of the product from the class.

Comment: I wanna use the list.sort(), but we are also required to use merge sort, and we also need to sort the products through there prices.

Comment: `<` automatically calls the `__lt__()` method.

Comment: `return self.name > other.name` should be `return self.name < other.name`.

Comment: I suggest you work with a smaller inventory list, then you can step through the function in a debugger and see where it's going wrong.

Comment: I tried all your suggestions but the output is still the same, what do you think's wrong?

Comment: If I knew what was wrong I would have written an answer instead of just posting comments about minor issues.

Comment: The incorrect `return` statement should be causing it to sort in the opposite order than you want, but it doesn't affect the sorting algorithm.

Comment: i tried to print the output of the return statement, and it was right

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/